# Kali Linux messed up installation on MacBook Pro

Tags: ethernet, macbook-pro, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux to a partition on my MacBook Pro. During the installation process it could not find the Ethernet card so a selected no Ethernet card. Now I'm stuck with nothing other than the loopback and since my laptop has no Ethernet port I can't connect to the Internet in order to download anything. I'm basically stuck with no options. I don't know what to do about this and there isn't a single answer on the Internet to this exact problem. How do I get Kali Linux to recognise the network card?

EDIT:

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

Gives me the network controller and wireless network adapter information

I can use my phone's connection via Bluetooth in order to download anything. But when I type ifonfig or iwconfig I only get one output 'lo' there's no 'en0' or 'eth0'

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest option (and a good backup option to have anyway) is to get a wired USB NIC, which are relatively inexpensive, running around $30 or so. Most should be compatible with Kali.

Comment: Why though since I have an internal NIC already why can't I just configure it to work on Kali Linux

Comment: You may be running into compatibility issues. MacBooks (and all other Macs) use an odd variant of EFI that is Apple-specific: it's neither fully EFI nor fully UEFI, being based on EFI with some UEFI functions added.

I'll note that Kali 2016.2 was released today after I made my post, which probably has a newer kernel than you've installed. That may also address the issue.